# Is it possible to change the font family for comments specifically by using the color customization settings of VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to change the font-family for the comments I write in my code.

I was looking around and found this snippet of code for changing the color of comments:

```json
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "textMateRules": [
      {
        "scope": [
          "comment",
          "comment storage.type",
          "comment variable",
          "comment support.variable",
          "comment support.class",
          "comment support.type",
          "comment entity.name.type",
          "comment entity.name.class",
          "comment keyword.operator"
        ],
        "settings": {
          "foreground": "#666666"
        }
      }
    ]
```

But adding `fontFamily` inside of `"settings"` doesn't work. Is it possible to change comments' font-family?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can modify the fontFamily of comments in that way.  See [vscode textmate theme rules](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensions/themes-snippets-colorizers#_textmate-theme-rules):

> TextMate themes assign a set of styles to one or more scopes. The styles are the foreground color, the background color and bold, italics and underline.

It appears you are limited to color and fontStyle.  Perhaps

```
"fontStyle": "italic",
```

will be enough to make your comments easily distinguishable?